# Appending jQuery UI Spinner Dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dynamic, append, jquery-ui-spinner

I'm having problems with the jQuery UI Spinner widget. It works fine when the input is added in the html; however, when I add the input dynamically it does not work. I created an example of the spinner not working when it is added dynamically here: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BsgCr/1/)

```
function injectSpinner(){
    console.log("Injecting Spinner");

    var p = document.createElement('p');
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    var text = document.createTextNode("Select a value:");
    var input = document.createElement('input');

    label.appendChild(text);
    label.setAttribute("for", "spinner");
    p.appendChild(label);

    input.setAttribute("id", "spinner");
    input.setAttribute("name", "value");
    p.appendChild(input);

    $("#spinner").spinner();

    $("#moduleArea").append(p);
};
```

I have used this method with a lot of the other jQuery UI widgets and there seems to be no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input has to be part of the DOM before you call .spinner() on it.
So please call `$("#moduleArea").append(p);` **before** `$("#spinner").spinner();`
[I have updated your fiddle accordingly](http://jsfiddle.net/BsgCr/2/).